# Relation between two different definitions for relative sequential compactness

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology

Building upon [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585584/definition-for-relatively-sequentially-compact/1586665#1586665) question in Math.SE, I think the following might be rather of interest for MO.

In the literature on measure theory, probability and functional analysis the definition of a subset $A \subseteq X$ of a topological space $X$ to be relatively sequentially compact is not unique:

1. $A$ is relatively sequentially compact in $X$ if its closure $\overline{A}$ in $X$ is sequentially compact, i.e. every sequence in $\overline{A}$ has a convergent subsequence (with limit in $\overline{A}$)
2. $A$ is relatively sequentially compact in $X$ if every sequence in $A$ has a convergent subsequence with limit in $\overline{A}$.

In definition 2 it is not really necessary to explicitely demand the limit to be contained in $\overline{A}$ (the limit of any sequence in $A$ is always contained in $\overline{A}$ and even in the sequential closure of $A$).

Clearly, 1 $\Rightarrow$ 2 but for general topological spaces $X$ the converse does not hold as shown in the linked Math.SE thread.
Another example can be also found in Meggonsin, "An Introduction to Banach Space Theory", p. 161, Exc. 2.15.

**Remark**: It seems to be not only the case that a few authors prefer some definition to the other but rather that roughly speaking half of the literature (I was reading so far) uses definition 1 and the other half definition 2. Both have advantages and disadvantages.

**Question**: Can the spaces $X$ in which 1 $\Leftrightarrow$ 2 for any subset $A \subseteq X$ be characterized by already familiar topological properties?

Note that for the weak topology on a Banach space $X$ these two definitions seem to be equivalent since I found versions of the Eberlein-Smulian theorem which equate weak relative compactness to weak relative sequential compactness with both definitions. But which property of the weak topology on $X$ is really used to equate these two definitions?

Comment: The standard sources that I have seen all use definition 2. As pointed out in the linked math.so item, with definition 1 you could have a sequentially compact set that is not relatively so. And in applying the Eberlein-Smulian theorem, there may be situations where you want to assume only the property in definition 2.

Comment: In Functional Analysis there is a widely used notion of an angelic space, introduced by Fremlin: this is a space in which a relatively countably compact space is relatively compact and compact subsets are Frechet-Urysohn. In such spaces both notions of sequential compactness seem to coincide. More information on angelic spaces can be found in the book [J.Kąkol, W.Kubiś, M.López-Pellicer, Descriptive topology in selected topics of functional analysis. Developments in Mathematics, 24. Springer, New York, 2011].

Answer (score 1):

On the matter of what definition is preferable. Let me add that the same question may be asked for the countably version, that has  *$\omega$-accumulation point* in place of *limit of a subsequence*:

3. $A$ is relatively countably compact in $X$ if its closure $\overline{A}$ in $X$ is countably compact, i.e. every sequence in $\overline{A}$ has a $\omega$-accumulation point (in $\overline{A}$).

vs

4. $A$ is relatively sequentially compact in $X$ if every sequence in $A$ has a $\omega$-accumulation point (in $\overline{A}$).

I think 2 and 4 are more standard than the variants 1, resp. 2; in fact it seems to me there are a number of reasons to prefer them.

- *Property of language*. Definitions (2) and (4) really describe relative properties, whereas (1) and (3) are just cases of the notion of sequential, resp. countable compactness, referred to the space $\overline A$.
- *Economy of language.* Why squandering locutions that can be used for situations (2) and (4), while (1) and (3) can be simply referred to as  “$\overline A$ is sequentially/countably compact” ?
- *Topological invariance.* Properties (2) and (4) seem somehow more relevant because they behave better under continuous maps. If $A\subset X$ is (2) resp (4) in $X$, and $f:X\to Y$ is a continuous map, then $f(A)$ is (2) resp (4) in $Y$. The same is not true for the odd counterparts (1) and (3).
- *Prevalence of the situation.* Here I'm vague, but I think situations (2) and (4) are quite common and relevant in the mathematical practice, because dealing with sequences taken from the set $A$ vs sequences taken from $\overline A$ can make a difference. The closure of $A$ in a weak topology may contain unknown wild objects (think of a subset $A$ of a Banach space $E$ and its closure in $E^{**}$ in the $\sigma(E^{**},E^*)$ topology, for instance).
- *Relevance in connection with important theorems*. It only comes to my mind the Eberlein-Shmulian theorem, but I think this great theorem alone, a Northwest Passage of Functional Analysis, is enough to ask for a special term for situations (2) and (4).

Answer (score 0):

One important class of spaces for which the two definitions mentioned in the post are equivalent, are the [first-countable spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-countable_space). One of the most important properties of any first-countable space $(X,\tau)$ is that given a subset $A\subseteq X$, a point $x$ lies in the closure of $A$ if and only if there exists a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in A which converges to $x$. Using this characterization, it is not hard to prove that definition (2)  implies definition (1).

Comment: Yes, this property is also satisfied for Fréchet-Urysohn spaces (a space $X$ is Fréchet-Urysohn if the sequential closure of any subset $A \subseteq X$ coincides with its closure $\overline{A}$). But does it follow from $1 \Leftrightarrow 2$ that $X$ is Fréchet-Urysohn? Recall that, an infinite-dimensional Banach space with the weak topology is not first-countable and I am not sure whether it is Fréchet-Urysohn but the fact $1 \Leftrightarrow 2$ seems to be still satisfied there.

Comment: Could you add a proof that for FU spaces, (2) implies (1)?